# Curious New Yorker typography

Tags: typography

Reading [this](http://www.newyorker.com/news/john-cassidy/only-republican-voters-can-stop-donald-trump-now) article in the *New Yorker* I notice this word 'reëxamined'. It's not the only one written like this, any other word with double vowels will be written similarly.

What is the point behind this use ?

Comment: It could be to note that the second "e" is pronounced differently than the first one. An umlaut is used different pronunciations in other languages (commonly German).

Comment: See answer to http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51042/why-does-the-i-in-naïve-have-two-dots - its about the word `naïve`, but the answer is the same. An alternative to the dotted e would to write re-examined, to separate the two e's.

Comment: I cannot find a reference for which words the New Yorker applies the diaeresis to. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a matter of the typographic style of the *The New Yorker*, a publication known for it idiosyncratic, slow-to-change, and close punctuation style.  The two dots are called a *diaeresis*, which appears on the second of a pair of vowels to put the reader on notice that the second vowel starts a separate syllable.  Note that a diaeresis is not an umlaut, which serves a different purpose in German.  Mary Norris explains all of this in her article ["The Curse of the Diaeresis"](http://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis).  The rules for its appearance are the publication's own.  They don't use it for *vacuum*, which might lead you to believe the editors consider the word to have only two syllables.  But it's not used for *zoology*, which surely has three.  Go figure.

Comment: What?? 'zoology' does not get a diaeresis in the New Yorker? _furiously scribble letter to the editor_

Comment: @Mitch I suggest my usual opening after "To whom it may concern":  *I am shocked and dismayed ....*

Comment: sampablokuper, I have no problems with your correcting an error (in this case the erroneous substitution of *cure* for *curse*).  But stay your hand at correcting my writing style.  I'm not sufficiently invested in this answer to reverse your edits, but this is not a habit you want to cultivate.

Comment: And if the style gets on your nerves you should take a diauretic!  That'll get you really pissed!

Comment: sampablokuper probably had to meet the minimum 6 characters limit in order for their suggested edit to pass through.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure (from years of reading *The New Yorker*) that the magazine adopted the use of diaeresis as an alternative punctuation to using a hyphen in situations where the final letter of a prefix is the same as the first letter of the stem word. That would explain why deadrat's examples of *vacuum* and *zoology* are not governed by the style rule.

Thus, *The New Yorker* prefers *reëducate*, *reëxamined*, *coöperation*, *coördinate*, and (perhaps) *antiïntellectual* to the alternative forms *re-educate*, *re-examined*, *co-operation*, *co-ordinate*, and *anti-intellectual*. I'm not entirely sure about this last example because *The New Yorker*'s style rules are extremely granular (and often sui generis), and it may be that the house style favoring diaeresis over hyphen applies only to **two-letter** prefixes where vowel duplication occurs at the interface of prefix and stem.

My guess is that the magazine adopted this approach decades ago, at a time when few publications would simply have used the style *reeducate* and *cooperation* (for example). But *The New Yorker* is an island of usage unto itself; its loyalty to elsewhere-long-abandoned punctuation is unlikely to influence other publications, except perhaps to say "Let's not be as nutty as *The New Yorker* about this." I, for one, admire the magazine's pertinacity.

Comment: I don't think two-letter, but perhaps one syllable (Wouldn't a word like "preëxisting" get a diæresis?).

Comment: It's one of the lovable quirks in The New Yorker's editorial style.  (It would be amusing to set one of their editors loose here for a few hours.)

Comment: @sumelic: I believe you are right about _preëxisting_, and your monosyllabic-prefix rule makes perfect sense as the explanation.

Comment: @SvenYargs -- Say that three times, fast.